# What is wrong with my app.config file?

Tags: .net, app-config

I have an app.config file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="TestKey" value="TestValue" />
  </appSettings>
  <newSection>
  </newSection>
</configuration>
```

And I'm trying to use it in this way:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ConfigurationFileMap(@"C:\app.config");  
System.Configuration.Configuration configuration = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(fileMap);
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working.  When I break and debug right after the file is read in, and I try to look at `configuration.AppSettings` I get an `'configuration.AppSettings' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'`.

I'm sure I'm reading the file, because when I look at configuration.Sections["newSection"] I am returned an empty `{System.Configuration.DefaultSection}` (rather than null).

I'm guessing I've got something very basic wrong...what's going on with AppSettings?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are using a wrong function to read the app.config.  OpenMappedMachineConfiguration is intended to open your machine.config file, but you are opening a typical application.exe.config file.
The following code will read your app.config and return what you'd expect.

```
    System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
    fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = @"C:\app.config";
    System.Configuration.Configuration configuration = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    MessageBox.Show(configuration.AppSettings.Settings["TestKey"].Value);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the 'newSection' element is causing the problem. Unless you add a 'configSections' element too, to declare what 'newSection' is, .NET won't be able to cast it.

You need something like:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="newSection" type="Fully.Qualified.TypeName.NewSection,   
  AssemblyName" />
</configSections>
```

In the first instance, I'd try removing the 'newSection' element to see if this improves the situation.

[This link](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/11/custom-configuration-sections-in-3-easy-steps.aspx) explains about Custom Configuration Sections.

Comment: Unforunately, that isn't it.  I put the newSection in just to make sure I was really loading the file.  Removing it makes no difference.

Answer (score 3):

If you read the documentation on MSDN on the function you try to use:

[OpenExeConfiguration MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437.aspx)

In the way you are using it will try to find the configuration of app.config.exe. If you do want to make use of appSettings, add them to the configuration of the config file from your application and then access them by using the configuration manager:

[Using appsetting .net MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx)

Comment: That's not too surprising...I didn't think OpenExeConfiguration was quite right, but since I wasn't having luck with the other option I thought I'd explore it.  I've deleted the edit to my question that I think probably just caused more confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Any time i've used a key in my webconfig i've done it like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <SectionGroup>
      Section Stuff
    </SectionGroup>
  </configSections>
<appsettings>
   <add key="TestKey" value="TestValue" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I don't fully understand why but it would always throw errors at me having app settings inside of configsettings.